# MySqlConnection ignores incorrect password when SQL username matches Windows account

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-authentication, database-connection

I have MySql Server with authentication_windows.dll plugin.
There I have windows account "test_win" and sql user "test_sql" with password "test".

Even if Integrated Security is set to false, as long as user id matches existing windows account, the connection is opened without any error.

I am trying on MySQL80 Enterprise with authentication_windows.dll plugin.

Example of my connection string:

> server=localhost;user id=test_win;database=mydb;Integrated Security=False;password=incorrect

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

Actual result: connection is opened and validated
I would expect "Access denied for @test_win (using password: YES)"

How can I force account validation except for Integrated security = false ?

Additional information:

Tested same scenario on MsSql with expected result

> Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=test_win;Password=incorrect
>
> Exception: Login failed for user 'test_win'

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: You need to use a different authentication driver. Seems like you are using the windows auth driver to connect to the database, when you need to use forms auth.

Comment: try `IntegratedSecurity=yes` without spaces not sure how you wrote it in your code.

Comment: @kirstech where can I specify it ? on the MySqlConnection instance?

Comment: @RaymondNijland in code I have MySqlConnectionStringBuilder with connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false; ... and then builder.ToString()... the spaces are probably just in this post due to my mistake

Comment: @TomášKohoutek if you check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html) both `IntegratedSecurity` and `Integrated Security` are acceptable and the values are `yes` and `no`, not `false`. The default is `no` so all you need to do is *not* specify `Integrated Security=False;` in your connection string

Comment: @TomášKohoutek not that it *can't* be a bug, or just intentional but .... unexpected behavior. The Windows auth plugin may be taking precedence over the user/password combination. Try creating the connection string yourself and include only the relevant options

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried... I only specified the false (or "no") value to force it somehow... but I think that once the user is recognized, the password is not included in validation and windows authentication is selected by default even if not specified in connection string
(my example: server=localhost;user id=test_win;database=mydb;password=incorrect) -> connection successfull